# How to disable Home and Back Button in android service

Tags: android, android-service, android-package-managers

How to disable Home and Back button click function in service when popup dialog open.

```
dialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialogs, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            //what should i do
        }
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
            //what should i do
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: `//what should i do` try returning true. It should message system that event has been handled, and it doesn't need to do anything else.

Comment: Thank you .. it is working fine.perfect answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your above code is working in your service you can simply return `true`.

```
dialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialogs, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            return true;
        }
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Note:** *returning `true` will indicate the system that you'll handle further events and there is no further forwarding of `event` is required*.

Answer (score 1):

**Set Cancel-able to false**

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);

dialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialogs, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
            //what should i do
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this won't prevent home button.

Comment: I edited my answer. But stopping home button work is not good idea. If application hangs when dialog is open how user perform any other operation?

Comment: that's how the question goes. if you have comments about the question, leave them under the question.

Comment: Okay. Next time I will